# datename method in sqlserver

Tags: sql-server

how to show the day (like : sunday,monday ...) in sql query
i write like this

```
select datename(day,getdate())
```

but it give numaric values but i want sunday,monday,tuesday..... please give some soulution

Comment: @surya: then you should do the polite and proper thing and accept the best answer / the one that really solved you problem. To accept the answer, please click on the check mark to the left of the answer below the "0" with the up- and down-arrow. If someone helps you - please be so kind as to accept the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

or datename(dw,getdate())

Answer (score 1):

try datename(weekday, getdate())

Answer (score 1):

DATENAME ( datepart, date )

[MSDN DATENAME](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174395.aspx)

e.g.

```
SELECT DATENAME(weekday,getdate())
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DATENAME(weekday, GETDATE())
```